# What permission do I need to edit a perl file on linux via Sublime

Tags: permissions, sublimetext3

Somehow I've made an error where my Perl files, located on a Linux server, must be set at 775 for me to edit them via Sublime, on my Windows laptop.

I can change the files to 755 and they'll run properly, but I can't edit them unless they're set to 775.  When I try to save them I get a Permission Denied error.

Everything is owned by www-data

> drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data    4096 Jun 10 08:00 cgi-bin

The Perl file within cgi-bin directory is as well

> -rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data  960 Jun 10 01:22 perly.pl

When I log in via the Sublime editor I log in as the original user I created my server with "danny", and he is a member of the www-data group.

Can anyone figure out where I making a mistake or the wrong assumption?

Comment: As outlined in your post, `755` is `r-x` for group and only the owner has `rwx` permissions; so being in the `www-data` group doesn't help because the group doesn't have write access. Using `775` should allow execution of the file just fine unless the server is configured to only execute files that aren't writable by anyone but the owner; is that the case here?

Comment: Well I took one Perl file, changed the owner to "danny", kept the group as www-data, and changed the permission to 755.  I can now edit the file, as well as run it from a browser.  If that's enough of a test, then I see what I did wrong